# Sequelize 2.0 Auto generate join table

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

When I created a N:M through HasMany in 1.7.x the sequelize will auto generate the join table for me, e.g. UserProjects

However, when I now create it in 2.0 using belongsToMany, it doesn't do the auto generation, how do I turn this option on?

Users.belongsToMany(models.Projects, {through: 'UserProject', as: 'Projects'});

Plus I'm having the notice "belongsToMany: not defining through or defining through as true has been deprecated, please provide a string or a model" which is an acknowledged bug, wonder if that's the issue

I am not calling .sync() but previously the association table is created anyway without calling sync. How do I sync just the association table?

Using mysql flavour

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with your syntax.

Did you ensure that you have `Projects.hasMany(models.Users, {through: 'UserProject', as: 'Users'});` ?

Comment: Hi, yup, and the set get methods works fine, it's just not doing the Create table if exists anymore. :(

Comment: in that case you might want to provide a bigger chunk of the syntax. the issue might not be within what you have provided.

Comment: @Calvintwr Does 2.0 require the sync()? previously I don't have that in my 1.7 and it just adds the join table anyway. I'll try adding the sync

Comment: #sync() is only used when you need to create the tables, which means that you only call it once, thereafter you don't need it again. I think you must however, call #sync() only after calling all associations.